# Installing rails on non-supported mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm, gnupg

I'm trying to install rails on my 2011 Macbook Air and I am running into issues. The latest supported MACOS for my laptop is High Sierra. The minimum requirement for installing GPG, is Mojave. GPG is a requirement for install RVM, which i want to use to install rails.There are a few ways I can see to approach this issue, but not sure what's best.

1. is there a way to still install GPG on my computer
2. Can i install RVM without installing GPG?
3. Should i just install rails without RVM?
4. Should i go nuclear and hack Mojave onto my laptop?

Any recommendations, or sympathy from other people who have gone through the same mission would be massively appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: You could just try [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) alternative to RVM.

Comment: true @eux is gpg not a requirement for anything else?

Comment: At least GPG is not a requirement for Ruby and Rails.